# String de fecha realizando cálculos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, spring-boot, google-chart-api

estoy intentando poblar un DataTable de google chart para generar un gráfico.
Hasta los momentos, pude hacer que la información viajara desde la base de datos (MySQL) hasta el controlador, y desde allí hasta la vista usando un ArrayList pero al momento de leer las fechas, algo sucede y éstas se restan:

En resumen: estoy enviando un Array con datos en formato 2019-05-21 y el JavaScript lo interpreta como una operación matemática, quedando 1.993.

Entiendo que pueda verse como un error básico, pero es mi primera vez trabajando con JavaScript y ya he dedicado varias horas leyendo documentación y no he encontrado alguna solución.

Código Controlador:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class indexController {
    
    @Autowired
    private IAccionService service;
    

    
    @GetMapping("chart_index")
    public String profileSettings(Model model) {
        
        String msg="holasoyundatodeprueba";
        String msg2="Fecha1";
        model.addAttribute("msg", msg);
        model.addAttribute("msg2", msg2);
        
        List<Acciones>accioneslst=service.listar_acciones();
        Acciones[] arrayAcciones = new Acciones[accioneslst.size()];
        arrayAcciones=accioneslst.toArray(arrayAcciones);
        
        ArrayList<String> arrayFechas = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayOpen = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayClose = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        
        for (Acciones acciones : arrayAcciones) {
            
            arrayFechas.add(acciones.getFecha().toString());
            arrayOpen.add(acciones.getOpen_value());
            arrayClose.add(acciones.getClose_value());
            System.out.println(arrayFechas.toString());
        }
        
        
        
        model.addAttribute("fechaGrafico",arrayFechas);
        model.addAttribute("openGrafico",arrayOpen);
        model.addAttribute("closeGrafico",arrayClose);
        
        return "chart_index";
        
    }
```

Código JavaScript (Google Chart: Line Chart) incrustado en la vista:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Gráfico de acciones</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles_chart.css" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      
      function drawChart() {
        var Fecha=[[${fechaGrafico}]];
        var Open=[[${openGrafico}]];
        var Close=[[${closeGrafico}]];
        
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); //Cambiado a DataTable
        data.addColumn('string','Fecha');
        data.addColumn('number','Open');
        data.addColumn('number','Close');
        
        for(i=0;i<Fecha.length;i++)
        data.addRow(["'"+Fecha[i]+"'",Open[i],Close[i]]);

        
        console.log(Fecha);
        
        var options = {
                title : "[[${msg}]]",
                curveType : 'function',
                backgroundColor : '#EDEEF0',
                width : '1323',
                height : '855',
                legend : 'none',
                chartArea : {
                    width : '1200',
                    height : '800'
                },
                colors : [ '#A6CEE3', '#1F78B4' ]
            };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Eso no es JavaScript,  es JAVA,  porfavor no confundas JavaScript con Java,  son cosas totalmente distintas.

Comment: Saludos. Mira en https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addColumn `addColumn` permite dato tipo `date` úselo; así mismo deberá cambiar ` ArrayList<String>` a  `ArrayList<Date>` (más bien el tipo de dato que retorna `acciones.getFecha()`); con ello `arrayFechas.add(acciones.getFecha().toString());` deberá quedar como `arrayFechas.add(acciones.getFecha());`.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr Hola! Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Ya había intentado lo que me comentas, sin embargo, al revisar la consola en el navegador, figura el siguiente error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value '2005' does not match type date in column index 0

En las revisiones que he hecho, me he fijado que el dato llega mal al guardarlo en la variable "Fecha" dentro del Script. Por lo que tengo la sospecha que no estoy formateando correctamente los datos desde el controlador.

Comment: @Riven Hola Rive, gracias por la respuesta. Estoy empezando a entender JavaScript, tal vez por eso no identifico aún las diferencias. Sin embargo, asumí que se trataba de JavaScript por 2 cosas:
1) El código corre dentro de la misma vista html.
2) El código está encerrado bajo las etiquetas Script indicando que el tipo de texto es "JavaScript".

También hago el alcance de que ese tipo de respuestas no contribuyen a la solución del problema que planteé. Sin embargo, si tienes otro criterio para identificar el uso de JavaScript, me gustaría conocerlo.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. Mira en https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes al parecer `addRow` no tiene forma de interpretarlo; hay que usar `new DATE(Año, Mes, Día)`; dependiendo como tengas ahorita tu código sería que extraigas (según como corresponda) de cada fecha esos componentes por separado y así crearlo. Ojo que enero no es 1 es 0; empieza de 0 a 11. Esto que menciono en **Código JavaScript** para que no modifiques mucho..

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a lo leido y que comentaste; te sugiero que así como tienes tu código (el que compartiste/publicaste) con fecha como `String`; en el **Código JavaScript** la función `drawChart` quede de  la siguiente forma:

```
function drawChart() {
   
   var Fecha=[[${fechaGrafico}]];
   var Open=[[${openGrafico}]];
   var Close=[[${closeGrafico}]];

   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); //Cambiado a DataTable
   data.addColumn('date','Fecha'); // Le ponemos que el tipo de datos es date; y no string
   data.addColumn('number','Open');
   data.addColumn('number','Close');


   // Aquí en el for sería el cambio
   for(i=0;i<Fecha.length;i++) {
      // Como el formato que recibes es solo AÑO-MES-DIA
      var fechaSplit = Fecha[i].split('-'); // Tendremos 3 elementos
      // data.addRow(["'"+Fecha[i]+"'",Open[i],Close[i]]); // Cambiamos esta
      data.addRow([new Date(parseInt(fechaSplit[0]), parseInt(fechaSplit[1])-1, parseInt(fechaSplit[2])),Open[i],Close[i]]); // Por esta
   }

        
   console.log(Fecha); // Desde luego esta se quita
        
   var options = {
                title : "[[${msg}]]",
                curveType : 'function',
                backgroundColor : '#EDEEF0',
                width : '1323',
                height : '855',
                legend : 'none',
                chartArea : {
                    width : '1200',
                    height : '800'
                },
                colors : [ '#A6CEE3', '#1F78B4' ]
            };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

   chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero al implementar la solución, me arroja el siguiente error en la consola del navegador: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Fecha[i].split is not a function
    at drawChart (chart_index:29)